# How to upgrade data content on installing new version package?

Tags: android, android-manifest

When I install a new version of package to AVD, old version of database is becoming a reason of different errors. How can I upgrade database (and all content in data/data/pack_name/) with installing new version of my app?

Answer (score 0):

did you even **TRY** to look at the documentation of SQLOpenHelper ? onUpgrade ????

Comment: yes but  I don't know when I must use it, and it is not a decision for other files in data